# Recuperar $_SESSION com Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, session

É correto/seguro setar uma Session no PHP e recuperar esse valor utilizando AJAX?

Estou criando uma aplicação utilizando checkout transparente do PagSeguro e preciso passar um valor como Referência (Identificador). Porém, por se tratar de um dado restrito, eu não gostaria de deixá-lo no Front do HTML. Aí eu fiz da seguinte maneira (exemplo):

No FRONT-END

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['ref'] = 123;
?>

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <button type="button" id="btnSession">Testar Sessão</button>

</body>
</html>
```

SCRIPT JQUERY com chamada AJAX

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnSession").on("click",function(){
        $.get("backend.php",
        function (res){
            console.log(res);
        })
    })
})
```

No BACK-END

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['ref'];
?>
```

Isso está funcionando e me atende perfeitamente. Porém, eu gostaria de saber se isso é correto e seguro para minha aplicação ou se tem uma forma melhor/ mais segura/eficaz de fazer isso com AJAX.

O objetivo dessa aplicação é:
Tenho um formulário HTML, irei passar seus valores para um SCRIPT JQUERY que irá fazer conexão com o PAGSEGURO e enviar esses dados via AJAX para uma outra página PHP. Essa página irá receber os dados e validar a compra. Porém, eu preciso informar uma variável REFERENCE que trata-se do ID do usuário. E se eu colocar essa variável no meu HTML, ela corre o risco de ser alterada. Por isso pensei em setar a variável REFERENCE através de uma SESSION na página que está o HTML e depois retornar seu valor na página de validação em PHP.
Ficou claro agora?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso não está incorrecto, mas não é de nem perto uma boa prática porque a $_SESSION e tudo que engloba dentro do objeto da mesma deveria ser acessada apenas pelo o escopo do próprio contexto que ela se aplica, traduzindo, apenas pelo backend.

Se você precisa manipular objetos ou qualquer coisa dentro do backend e precisa que algo seja mudado no contexto da $_SESSION você deveria ter um acessor a ela que não fosse implicatamente como você está fazendo, um token, JWT ou qualquer coisa parecida.

Mas considerando o estilo de script que você está fazendo aparentemente é algo que você ainda está aprendendo.

Mas no mundo do PHP tu tem que tomar cuidado com todas as superglobais (variaveis $_XXXX), pois basicamente essas variaveis podem (e fazem) um grande estrago na sua aplicação se alguém de fora mal intencionado tiver acesso a elas.

O PHP te da muita liberdade, mas essa liberdade tem um preço, que é bem alto na verdade, então tente tomar cuidado em relação a isso.

Comment: Interessante, teria algum link sobre o material que mencionou para eu dá uma estudada por favor?

Comment: O inicio dos estudos vem aqui -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Answer (score 1):

Sobre a sessão, não há nenhum problema de segurança em si, apenas os problemas inerentes ao próprio sistema de `SESSION` (como [`Man-in-the-Middle`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Man-in-the-middle_attack), [`Session Prediction`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_Prediction), [`Session Fixation`](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Session_fixation) e problemas relacionados ao XSS/CSRF, principalmente se está usando as configurações padrões no PHP).

Você pode ler algumas sugestões de [segurança aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.security.ini.php), já que por padrão as configurações do PHP são completamente inseguras, como tudo no PHP. Adicionalmente [recomendo ler isto](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/04/fast-track-safe-and-secure-php-sessions).

O problema é no `Ref`. Você diz que ele é "um dado restrito", mas isto não define exatamente o que ele é. Bem, qualquer um analisando o trafego de rede (até pelo "Network" no navegador) terá acesso ao `ref` (devido ao `echo $_SESSION['ref']`), assim deixando de ser um dado secreto. Isso também pode ser um dado manipulado pelo cliente, como qualquer outro dado, já que o código do AJAX é controlado pelo cliente.

---

Além disso, pode existir problemas que não são relacionados à segurança. Por exemplo, o `$_SESSION['ref']` PODE ser modificado se o usuário entrar em outra página, considere:

> Pagina-1.php

> ```
> $_SESSION['ref'] = 1
> ```

> Pagina-2.php

> ```
> $_SESSION['ref'] = 2
> ```

*No seu código o `ref` não é alterado, só tem um e é único.* Mas, considerando que ele possa ser alterado (existam mais de um produto, por exemplo). Se o usuário acessar o `Pagina-1` terá o `1` como setado como o valor. Porém, se em outra nova aba/janela acessar o `Pagina-2` o `ref` será alterado para `2`. Agora vem o problema, se ele abrir a janela que está com o `Pagina-1` aberta, quando executar o AJAX,   na `Pagina-1`, ele usará o valor `2` e não o `1`.

Isto não é um problema de segurança, mas é um grave problema de usabilidade e um comportamento não-desejável.

---

Sobre uso `JWT` e `Token`, comentado pelo Fabio William Conceição, é desnecessário. Afinal o próprio `session` já possui um token (o `PHP_SESSID` é um token, se for analisar) e ele é utilizado para acessar os dados daquela sessão (*"os arquivinhos lá no /tmp"*). O JWT pode causar mais problemas, recomendaria o [Paseto](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-paragon-paseto-rfc-00) (ele não usa algoritmos arcaicos como o JWT, e nem permite facilmente altera-los, e força de algoritmos melhores como Ed25519, ChaCha20Poly1305 e Blake2), mas não recomendaria o uso neste caso. Isto seria útil apenas se pretende não salvar os dados no servidor. Lembre-se que tanto sua solução atual, como o JWT e quanto o Paseto não são capazes de defender contra o [`replay-attack`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack).

---

Sobre ter melhores soluções: existe. Há melhores maneira de alcançar o mesmo objetivo. Mas, não há detalhes na pergunta (dê onde vem o `ref`, para que ele serve, se existe outra autenticação, porquê ele é secreto...) e nenhuma das soluções que pensei seria tão simplificado quanto ao que fez, somados isto impede de postar aqui uma "outra solução".

Comment: Entendi amigo, vou ler cada link que compartilhou comigo, obrigado. Em relação 3ª estrofe do seu comentário, o " echo $_SESSION['ref'] " foi apenas um exemplo... em relação a 4ª estrofe, o " $_SESSION['ref'] = 123; " foi outro exemplo também... O que preciso fazer é o seguinte: Preciso passar uma variável REF que identifica o usuário. Se eu colocar esse REF no html, o usuário poderá alterá-lo. Por isso pensei em setar uma Session com o REF dele e depois retornar esse valor na página que o AJAX irá acessar, dessa maneira fica tudo no PHP. Entendeu?

Answer (score 0):

A session é um valor que deveria ser usado no lado servidor, manipular isso no frontend não é uma boa prática, não é seguro pois é muito mais fácil de ter acesso por outras pessoas.

Se está fazendo integração do PHP com PagSeguro, pode fazer todas as operações do lado server, tudo em PHP, evitando trafegar informações sensíveis para o cliente.

Na própria página do PagSeguro tem uma biblioteca com exemplos: [https://m.pagseguro.uol.com.br/](https://m.pagseguro.uol.com.br/v3/guia-de-integracao/tutorial-da-biblioteca-pagseguro-em-php.html?_rnt=dd#!rmcl)
Tem também o projeto no GitHub: https://github.com/pagseguro/php

Ou seja, evite trafegar essa informação, faça uma chamada ajax com o mínimo de dados sensíveis e deixe o código na parte server com o PHP.

Comment: Entendi. Estou me baseando na biblioteca do PagSeguro mesmo, porém lá eles passam essa Referência para o Front e eu não achei isso muito seguro. Aí eu queria fazer essa intermediação da página do formulário e a página de validação em AJAX. Se eu fizer sem o AJAX é tranquilo, mas via AJAX eu não encontrei um método seguro ainda.

Comment: Não entendi o "manipular isso no frontend não é uma boa prática". A manipulação ainda ocorre no PHP, portanto no servidor.

Comment: PS: Não fui eu quem dei negativo.

Comment: manipular no frontend eu quis dizer pegar o valor da session e trazer para o javascript, quis dizer que pode fazer isso tudo no PHP sem precisar desse valor no javascript ;)
bem não entendi o negativo, mas enfim

Comment: @Inkeliz eu havia pensado o mesmo... apesar de ser uma página HTML, acima eu coloco um PHP setando a SESSION, por isso achei que seria seguro e de boas.

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu não passo o valor da SESSION para o JavaScript. Eu justamente pensei em usar a SESSION para não fazer isso... na página HTML eu insiro a SESSION com o PHP no topo e depois retorno esse valor na última página PHP que será acessada via AJAX. Entendeu?

Comment: mas se executar `echo $_SESSION['ref']` está retornando o valor da session para a chamada ajax certo?